# Adding an existing module to a worksheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I got a worksheet with a vba module. It works fine. I copied this worksheet and created a second worksheet so I would use different data here. but on this new worksheet module doesn't work. How should I add it to the new worksheet or is there anything else I should do? thanks.

VBA code:

```
 Function Super_match(fin As Range, LOD As Range)
   Dim test_arr As Variant
   fin_arr =   Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(fin))
lod_arr = LOD

ReDim test_arr(1 To UBound(fin_arr))
For l = 1 To UBound(fin_arr)
    test_arr(l) = 0
Next l


For i = 1 To UBound(lod_arr, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(lod_arr, 2)
         For k = 1 To UBound(fin_arr)
           If fin_arr(k) = lod_arr(i, j) Then
             test_arr(k) = 1
           End If
         Next k
    Next j

If Application.WorksheetFunction.And(test_arr) Then
    Super_match = 1
    Exit Function
End If

For l = 1 To UBound(fin_arr)
    test_arr(l) = 0
Next l

Next i
Super_match = 0


Debug.Print Super_match1
End Function
```

and the formula for the module:

```
=Super_match(A2:B2,$H$2:$M$41)
```

Comment: It would be hard to tell without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @TrippKinetics  ok, I added the code to the question

Comment: When you say "...it doesn't work", what do you mean? Do you get an error? If so, what does the error say, and what line (click "Debug")?

Comment: It doesn't give any error. The output in the cell should be either 0 or 1. but it shows only 0 when it is actually 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add this function to a code module, remove it from your sheet modules, and it can then be used on any sheet.

To add a code module:

- In the VBE (coding window), go to the menu item "Insert"
- Select "Module"
- Cut and Paste your function into this module
- Remove any other instances of your function from other sheets
- Ensure you are good by selecting "Debug" -> "Compile VBA Project"

You will only get negative feedback if there is a problem. If it compiled successfully, then the "Compile VBA Project" menu item will be greyed out now.

You should be able to use your function in any sheet's cells now (within this Workbook).

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand what you tried to suggest.